# How to install Google Play Service in Xamarin Android Player

Tags: xamarin, google-play-services, xamarin-android-player

How to install Google Play Service in Xamarin Android Player. I have found the link https://university.xamarin.com/resources/how-to-install-google-play-on-android-emulator which does not work in windows. It does not allow me to drop the  Google Play Services .zip file from [www.teamandroid.com/gapps/](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) .Any suggestion or link please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use the android emulator that ships with the current version of Android Studio (by now 2.1). Google did a good job and a major overhaul with that version. It now is as fast as Genymotion or the Xamarin Android Player. Plus it as Google services support build in.

Comment: Yes... i have tested it.. it is working. I am using Android Emulator now as Xamarin Android Player is not working for me.  Thanks!